# "What did she think as she walked in the park?" vs. "What was she thinking as she walked in the park?"

Tags: questions, progressive-aspect

1. What **did** she **think** as she walked in the park?
2. What **was** she **thinking** as she walked in the park?

I wonder what is the possible difference in meaning between the two sentences.

I wonder also how the meaning would change if we add **about**:

3. What **did** she **think about** as she walked in the park?
4. What **was** she **thinking about** as she walked in the park?

Which sentence of the four would be best suited to ask for the contents of the woman's thoughts?

---

(based on a sentence from [a text I was proofreading](http://lang-8.com/1451389/journals/169408113377719852632688550408438449198) at lang-8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What was she thinking* is an idiom that expresses surprise at someone's carelessness or thoughtlessness. So, Sentence 2 could be synonymous with Sentence 1, or Sentence 2 could be expressing surprise that she was walking in the park. (Perhaps the park is known to be a dangerous place.)

Adding the word *about* eliminates the ambiguity with the idiom. I would say that Questions 1, 3, and 4 are all pretty much synonymous: they inquire about the thoughts that were running through her mind as she walked in the park, although Questions 3 and 4 seem to ask about multiple thoughts, while Question 1 could be construed to imply that she was thinking about one thing at a certain point in time, and the writer is wondering about that one thing.

They are all fine in regards to a woman's thoughts. They would be fine for a man's thoughts, too – all you'd need to do is change the pronouns:

> What did he think about as he walked in the park?